# How should I get rid of this error of " Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1"

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I facing this issue while executing the code

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1

I have used SharedPreferences for referring the userid

what shall I do ot rectify the error.

```
    private void saveUserData(){
            CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users");
            DocumentReference documentReference = ref.document(sp.getUserId());

            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    String name = documentSnapshot.getString(Constants.NAME);
                    String profilepic = documentSnapshot.getString(Constants.PROFILE_PIC);
                    String email = documentSnapshot.getString(Constants.EMAIl);

                    sp.setUserData(Constants.NAME, name);
                    sp.setUserData(Constants.PROFILE_PIC, profilepic);
                    sp.setUserData(Constants.EMAIl, email);

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What does `sp.getUserId()` return?

Comment: user id of the signed in user

Comment: What is the exact value of the string?

Comment: it retrieved from Firestore database, which auto generated user id

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The exact value is the issue here.

Comment: Please tell us what Doug Stevenson asked for and please also responde with @